# Action returns empty when I'm using Controller.File method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a PDF file save in my server. Now I'm trying to return this file as a Content-Disposition=inline.

So I wrote this:

```
public FileResult Test()
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();

    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.pdf", FileMode.Open))
    {
        fs.CopyTo(ms);
    }

    ms.Position = 0;

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");

    return File(ms, "application/pdf");
}
```

But in my browser (Chrome) I get a empty pdf.
I tried other browsers and get this:

- I.E. 8 (or less) - Do not work.
- I.E. 9 - Works.
- Chrome (46.0.2490.71) - Do not work.
- FireFox (32.0) - Works.

And I have another page in my application that is using pretty much the same code and works for all browsers.

Anyone can help me to understand why this strange behavior in some browsers and others not?

**UPDATE**
I tried to change my PDF in this code (like the same code but another pdf) and works for all browsers.

So is it possible that the content of the PDF is causing that? I tried and both pdfs are open fine in Adobe Reader and Win 8 Default PDF Reader.

As @Odrai request I tried too:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test");
```

But didn't work too and change the way that file is received (with attachment the browser make a download instead to open the file). I need to open in inline mode.

As @dustmouse request I tried to open the pdfs directly in the browsers and the same problem occurs.

So now I understand it's not a program problem, I intend to close this question. But before that is there other place that I can put this question (like other forum related with stackoverflow, i.e. code review or something)?

Comment: Please make sure you're pasting in exactly what code you have. At first blush, `C:File.pdf` looks problematic because it's missing a `\` character. Doesn't necessarily explain why you get something in some browsers but not others, but it is a problem.

Comment: Try to use backslashes: filename=\test.pdf\

Comment: Yes, to your update, if it works with one PDF but not with another, then the PDF itself could certainly be the problem, but it's difficult to say with such a limited sample of data

Comment: @BrianWarshaw I correct the filename problem. The problem was I updated the string when I copied the code to stackoverflow, but I erased more chars than was needed.

Comment: This should work: Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

Comment: Jonny, are the file sizes of the two PDFs comparable?

Comment: No, the first (the one is generating problems) is very very slow (2K) and the other is 54k. Do you think this can be the problem?

Comment: What happens when you try to open the problem PDF directly in your browsers?

Comment: @dustmouse this is a good question, the same described behavior (empty page) happen.

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi Is the PDF large?  You might be able to inspect it for errors in a program like IrfanView.  Not sure though...

Comment: no, the PDF has something around 2Kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33311455/1233788) by [@AaronSieb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16911/aaronsieb):

This appears to be a bug in recent versions of Chrome. It was reported on October 14th, 2015 and appears to be fixed in recent builds.

For me, updating to Chrome 46.0.2490.80 solved the issue.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543018